# Why my winform datagridview doesn't fill all the width of my form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a control that is as wide as the form. Then I setup the grid with

```
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
```

When running the grid is empty and doesn't fill all the width. When adding data nothing changes either. Why ?

Comment: that should work.  are you sure the grid isn't in a panel or some other container?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting docking of controls working at design-time.  It shouldn't need to change at runtime.